# how to close jframe besides setvisible

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

i want to calling form2 from form1 using command new form2().show, this.setVisible(false).
I want to ask how to close form1 without using setvisible(). because setVisible only hide it but did not close the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**-** You can use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)` method to close the form1 when you make the form2 visible.